# Maven scp and extract plugin

Tags: zip, maven, scp

As part of a development deployment - I need to SCP a zipped folder of assets to a virtual machine, and then extract it there.

Is there a plugin(s) that will do this, before I roll my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the `maven-antrun-plugin` is perfect for this kind of thing.

Taken from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922157/copy-and-unzip-files-to-remote-machine-ant)

```
    <profiles> 
        <profile> 

            <id>deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>

                <plugins>   
                    <plugin>          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>ftp</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <failOnError>false</failOnError>

                                <tasks>

                                    <fileset id="zipfiles.to.copy" dir="${archives.source}" includes = "*.zip">
                                        <include name = "*unminified.zip"/>
                                        <include name = "*thirdparty.zip"/> 
                                    </fileset>
                                    <!-- copy the archives to the remote server -->
                                    <scp todir="${user}:${password}@${vagrant.host}:${archives.destination}">
                                        <fileset refid="zipfiles.to.copy" />
                                    </scp>

                            <!-- Build the command line for unzip - the idea here is to turn the local
                                 paths into the corresponding paths on the remote, i.e. to turn
                                 C:\path\to\zipfiles\file1.zip;C:\path\to\zipfiles\file2.zip... into
                                 /home/testuser/archives/file1.zip /home/testuser/archives/file2.zip

                                 For this to work there must be no spaces in any of the zipfile names.
                             -->
                             <pathconvert targetos="unix"  pathsep=" " property="unzip.files" refid="zipfiles.to.copy">
                                <map from="${basedir}/${archives.source}" to="${archives.destination}" />
                             </pathconvert>

                            <!-- execute the command.  Use the "-d" option to unzip so it will work
                            whatever the "current" directory on the remote side -->
                            <sshexec host="${vagrant.host}" username="${user}" password="${password}"
                                command="/bin/sh -c '
                                for zipfile in ${unzip.files}; do
                                /usr/bin/unzip  -o -d ${unzip.destination} $$zipfile ; done '" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

The one thing to be aware of is the use of your `${archive.source}` and `${basedir}` in the `pathconvert` command.

I made it this way because you need to explicit with the full path name in the pathconvert - but you want to be relative in sourcing where they're from in the first place.